# MongoDB StartSession failed commit and rollback

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-session

I am working with the Laravel framework and using MongoDB. So I need to commit and roll back the collection save, but I get the following error in response.

> Server does not support sessions

Does my MongoDB installation not support sessions? If not, how can I enable sessions?

```
$session = DB::getMongoClient()->startSession();
$session->startTransaction();
try {  
    // Query
    $lead = Leads::create($data);
    $session->commitTransaction();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $session->abortTransaction();
}
```

This is the version of Mongodb I am using
mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.24-3-g78e64a697a
Just copied to bin and running

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you connect to single mongoDB instance.
You need to connect to replicaSet with version >= 4.0 to support transactions+sessions. For sharded cluster you need version >= 4.2 at least to support transactions+sessions.
For development/testing you can convert your single mongodb deployment  at least to replicaSet with single PRIMARY for mongodb version>=4.0.

Comment: I did not understand.Can you please explain

Comment: Please, provide some more details about your deployment as a beginning the mongodb version ,  if it is standalone , replicaSet  or  sharded cluster  etc. ?